# How to enable read/write to access database with password (Windows-Form C#)?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to enable read/write in access database protect with a password, but I read-only.
I have tried this:

```
return "provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0;" +  
       " data source=" +  
       "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory" +  
       "DebtManagementSystem.accdb;" +  
       "Jet OLEDB:Database Password = muqtada!;" +  
       "User Id=admin;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

but it doesn't work!

the OleDbException is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Operation must use an
> updateable query.    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
> hr)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
> dbParams, Object& executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
> executeResult)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
> behavior, String method)    at
> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
> DebtManagementSystem.Model.DatabaseProvider.runCommand(String query)

Comment: Please show the code that uses that string. We need it to understand the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get user and password from ConnectionStringSettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900201/get-user-and-password-from-connectionstringsettings)

Comment: Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486081/password-with-special-characters-in-connectionstring

Comment: `Operation must use an updateable query` is a common error that's rarely related on how you connected to the database and if it's protected. If you share that query, we can likely help, but be sure to first check https://stackoverflow.com/q/537161 and others for potential fixes to make sure it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Did you really post your password on a public site?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because I put the access database file in program files in Windows so Windows did not let me modify the file.

The solution to the problem:

1. Copy the database file from `C:\File Programs` to another directory.
2. Or try to create a setup file for your program, this can help you to get Windows permission to modify database files.